# Cloudwatch log insights sum() set default 0 value when no logs are present

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to run the following Cloudwatch log insights query for two different log stream sources. However, when one or both streams have no entries, the sum() function returns a void result instead of 0. Because of that, I can't use that result in another stats operation. Do you know if it's possible to circumvent this behavior and make the sum() function return 0 when there are no results? Thanks!

```
stats
  sum(raw.stream_1.TotalBill) as stream_1_bill,
  sum(raw.stream_2.TotalBill) as stream_2_bill,
  stream_1_bill + stream_2_bill as total_bill
```

Expected result:

```
stream_1_bill: 0
stream_2_bill: 1
total_bill: 1
```

Received result:

```
stream_1_bill: 
stream_2_bill: 1
total_bill:
```

Answer (score 3):

I can achieve the desired result by using the coalesce function.

```
COALESCE(SUM(stream_1_bill),0)
```